# http module cant get correct page url

Tags: url, httpmodule

Hi i got a very noob question to ask . I am using http module to do a access right. Let say the user is 'admin' then he got authorized to view the page.The http module will get the access right from the database based on the page url, thereafter the http module will determine the user is allowed to access or not .

Here is my sample coding :

```
 public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AcquireRequestState += new EventHandler(context_AcquireRequestState1);

    }



    void context_AcquireRequestState1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

           string requestUrl = application.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath.ToString().Trim();
            //return last string of .aspx
         string   requestAspx = requestUrl.Substring(requestUrl.LastIndexOf('/') + 1).Trim();

    }
```

but the httpmodule will run several time. It cant get the url correctly.
For example first time it may get ~/Module/Admin/Role/RoleManagementList.aspx.
then second time  will get the wrong url ~/favicon.ico.Can anyone help me solve this problem? thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not getting the "wrong" url.  The user's browser is simply making a different request for a different resource.  You http module will execute for each http request, which will mean one for each resource in addition to the "page" such as favicons (displayed in the browsers url, and sometimes requested even if you don't have one) or images, external .css, external .js files, etc. referenced on the page (unless they are directly served by IIS bypassing the ASP.NET stack).   You will need to consider all of these urls in your module.

Depending on how tightly you control your deployment environment,you may also/instead be able to exempt certain file extensions from every hitting asp.net by having IIS simply serve them directly.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972953.aspx

Comment: Hi thank for your comment . then got any solution to get the correct http url?For example i want get the url such as ~/Module/Admin/Role/RoleManagementList.aspx.Or mayb can do on another step of http module ?such as preInt or other?

Comment: You're thinking about it in the wrong way.  You will be given the url of the request - you can't "get" a different url.  You will have to decide how you want to react to the url you are given.  So, depending on your requirements, you might decide for example, that you'll simply pass through any urls not ending in .aspx.  Or you might simply decide to pass through urls ending in ".ico" or whatever.  Only you can decide how you want to react to them.

Comment: Hi nathan . thank for your help . However i still got one question to ask u. Can i use http module to control the button visible ? Let say i get the access right from the database. Then i am not allowed to delete.So all the Delete button on the page's visible are set to false.Isit posible to make it?Mayb using the findControl method

Comment: Not easily or reliably.  If you want to disable individual buttons you will be better off using a different approach.  You might consider using the Membership API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx) in conjunction with HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole(...) in the actual page code to disable the buttons.  In general though, to truly enforce role based security,you should do the security checks around the actual code preforming the delete action.  Only disabling the buttons (while good for user friendly UI) may be hacked to allow deletion even without permission.